# How to automate GPG file decryption over SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting, automation, gpg

I would like to use GnuPG to decrypt short messages that are stored on a
remote host (running Linux), i.e.:

1. `ssh [<user>@]<host>`
2. `gpg -d <file-to-decrypt>`
3. interact with gpg-agent and/or just type in the password
4. close SSH connection

but in a more automated way. I just want to type a single command and the script should do the rest (except for (interactive) input of the password), i.e.:

1. `remote-gpg [<user>@]<host> <file-to-decrypt>`
2. [query for password without echoing it back in plaintext]
3. [dump the decrypted text on stdout] AND close the SSH connection

My main challenge is merging the "ssh" and "gpg" step.

I am looking for a simple and effective way to achieve this:

- with as little dependencies on the *client* side (ideally, just `ssh` +
  core utilities)
- without messing a lot with sockets and pipes on the server side
- with no assumption about whether `gpg-agent` is running on the server

So, solutions such as writing a GNU `expect` script are out of question.

**Motivation**: A typical use case would be using a phone (running Android) to retrieve an encrypted message (e.g., a password) from the remote server. Closing the connection upon information delivery is desired because you might forget logging out before your phone gets lost/stolen, and the thief cannot retrieve additional information without guessing the password (since password is queried every time). Finally, removing your phone's SSH key from server's authorized_keys file is all it takes to prevent a security breach.

By the way, would there be any additional security risks with that approach (as compared to the 4-step manual process)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ssh -t user@host gpg -d file
```

I don't think it has to be more complicated than that.

The decrypted output will be echoed back to your terminal.  The `-t` option asks ssh to request a tty, which is needed so that gpg can prompt on your terminal for the password.

This seems no more or less secure to me than your 4-step method.

Answer (score 1):

tldr you want someone to write the code for you. Lucky for you I already have something similar.

decrypt.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get our original tty and turn off -echo
stty_orig=`stty -g` stty -echo 
read Pass
# type in your pass for gpg.
gpg --passphrase="$Pass" --no-tty -d $1
# Output goes to STDOUT
stty $stty_orig
```

Call it by:

```
ssh -t user@host 'decyrpt.sh File'
```

Assumptions:
You file is in the home directory, and decrypt.sh is in your $PATH.

Comment: I didn't request the code, but it is always welcome - thanks!

Comment: I think `stty_orig=`stty -g` stty -echo` should be 2 lines. The way you used it works, but has a different meaning.